# Is there a way of pulling off a report from M2 that shows stock against each SKU - specifically those with catalog view

Tags: stock, stock-availability

I would like to pull off a report to show which SKU's are in stock on Magento - specifically the main SKU's not by size.

Is this possible?

Comment: Hi Hillary, if the answer was not looking for, it is helpful for me to know your feedback. This helps me to answer more accurately next time. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Magento default export feature for this I believe.

Go to `System/Export` in the Magento backend. Select **Stock Sources** (like the screenshot below), and click continue. Magento will record your setup and put it in a queueing system.

If your system is configured correctly, a link of the generated stock file should appear once the queue will have processed your specific action.

Then, unless the data in the file are not usable at your end, you should have a stock report.

[image]